# Open a all http links from Windows in my UWP App

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, http-protocols

I am making a UWP app which opens all the http/https protocol links clicked in the Windows. In short it's acts same as a Default Browser.

I used the following to associate with http/https protocols

```xml
      <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
            <uap:Protocol Name="http">
                <uap:DisplayName>httpUWP</uap:DisplayName>
            </uap:Protocol>
        </uap:Extension>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
            <uap:Protocol Name="https">
                <uap:DisplayName>HttpUWP</uap:DisplayName>
            </uap:Protocol>
        </uap:Extension>
      </Extensions>
```

and a method to handle the launch `protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)`

The App compiles good. I set my app as default opener for `http` and When I try to open a link from `Win + R` or somewhere from system, The app gives out a `File system error (-2147219196)`

So, What am I supposed to do now?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid `http` and `https` are among the URI scheme names that are [reserved for the operating system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/reserved-uri-scheme-names?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) so you cannot associate these with your app.

You may still [change the default browser](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-your-default-browser-in-windows-10-020c58c6-7d77-797a-b74e-8f07946c5db6) in Windows though.

Comment: I already set my App as default and When I open a link, The App starts, shows the splash screen and the system gives that error.

Comment: You still shouldn't associate your app with any reserved URI schemes.

Comment: It makes sense to have some reserved stuff. But in reserved file type, even `.mp3` is listed. So, Does that mean no UWP app can be a Default Music Player ?

Comment: It means that it shouldn't associate with that protocol. The default app for a specific type of file is an OS setting that cannot be "hijacked" by a custom app basically.